# RESTful API call from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, rest, api

I'm attempting to access the online API of http://api.football-data.org/index using Excel VBA to eventually populate an excel sheet with a click of a button. Currently I have:

```
Sub apiTest()
  Dim oRequest As Object
  Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
  oRequest.Open "GET", "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/354/fixtures/?matchday=22", False
  oRequest.SetRequestHeader "X-Auth-Token", "replace this with my api token"
  oRequest.Send
  MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
End Sub
```

According to the site, all I need to do is to add the X-Auth-Token field to the header and it should work. However, when I try to run this the response body says "The resource you are looking for is restricted". Am I using WinHTTPRequest improperly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked [its documentation](http://api.football-data.org/docs/v1/index.html). The error (403 Restricted Resource) is to do with the followings:

- the resource is only available to authenticated clients
- the resource is only available to donating clients
- the resource is not available in the API version you are using

Also, X-Response-Control seems to be included as request header (See the doc).

Comment: The request I was using must be restricted to donating clients then. Weird, since he claims his site is 'free' and that request is used as an example in the code samples section. Thanks a bunch

Comment: I found there is sample url which works regardless of authentication, which is http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/424/fixtures?matchday=7 You can try develop with this url first before you get authentication through paying or donating.